# Single page app + node.js backend (REST) + CMS - best concepts/practices

Tags: node.js, rest, web-applications, content-management-system, single-page-application

We are going to build big social web app. We have to implements 2 big modules:

1. FrontEnd - single page app (Backbone.js)
2. CMS - system to manage contents of FrontEnd (daily content, sponsors, banners, links, special offers, upload media etcetc)

FrontEnd will use Node.js powered REST api which will use DB in the cloud (PG or Mongo - didnt decide yet).

My question is: should CMS also use same REST api as FrontEnd? Or should we make separate app (not node.js neccessery) for CMS that would "talk" with db in the cloud directly? My question arises because on previous project we had this issue:

1. Single REST api for FrontEnd and CMS.
2. When we wanted new functionality in CMS we had to implement it in RESTapi - and then we had to restart whole APP (RESTapi) which was problematic in production...

So:

1. Implement 2 RestApis - one for FrontEnd and one for BackEnd?
2. Implement 1 RestApi for FrontEnd and implemnt CMS as separate app talking directly to database?

How do you do it?

---

Out goal is to implement super-fast FrontEnd and Big/Heavy CMS (its is going to be bigger than FrontEnd). So we are thinking of completly separating CMS module from FrontEnd module. Eventual need for communication between modules would be implemented through redis pub/sub for example - What do you think?

Comment: Node.js ain't the best at it so if i were you i use nginx for the CMS and reverse proxying for the Node REST api(node.js).

Answer (score 0):

Software architecture decisions are always very contextual - the people most qualified to make the call are you and your team, since you know way more than we do. That being said, based on the info you've shared, here are some things to consider:

1. Content Management as a problem space is pretty mature. Unless part of your revenue model involves innovations in how you handle Content Management, you would be unwise to build one. There are fantastic CMSes both open source and commercial, ranging in price from hundreds of dollars to hundreds of thousands. I cannot caution you strongly enough against the common developer fallacy to discount the value of our own time. Even if you spend an entire engineer's salary-worth on a CMS, you'll almost certainly come out ahead.
2. An architecture that uses a CMS should reflect the reality of #1, that CMSes are mature and stable. You want a strong and well-defined interface boundary between the parts of your system that are unique to you and specific to your revenue model, and the parts that are interchangeable with COTS (commercial off-the-shelf) - even if you *do* end up building it yourself (which again, I strongly caution against) - you'll run into impedance mismatch problems that are *very* hard to get out of and create friction to new feature delivery across the entire system if you design something as if it's bespoke when it's not (or vice versa).